# Profile2 add fields as content type

Tags: nodes, users

Is it possible to assign a content type to a field using profile2 module ? The website is developed in Drupal 7.

For example i have a content type product and another one images. I would like to have a profile which has as fields all the fields from product content type and also to be able to add more than 1 image content type to the same profile.

Comment: please add more details

Comment: @monymirza i've added.

Comment: @Gigi Becali: Your question needs more clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

Please check out [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) Module.
It might help.

Comment: No ! I would like to assign a content type to a profile2 profile.